# Is it possible to run Java-GUI programs under Dos systems

Tags: java, dos

I was surprised if there is any way to run Java Swing or AWT under a DOS operating system, like freedos. Is there any other way to run a Java GUI under DOS?

Comment: I don't think you can run **GUI** application on freeDOS.

Comment: Why in the name of the lovely unicorns and fiery dragons would you want THAT!?

Comment: @Bobby - 2012 is coming, we must be prepared for everything:P

Comment: @Bobby, it's a perfectly cromulent thing to want!

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly DOS, but you can try [Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html) which is like 'ncurses' for Java ?

Answer (score 1):

There was a port of [Kaffe](http://web.archive.org/web/20100702163956/http://www.kaffe.org/ports.shtml) for DOS, but it could only run headless (without GUI). So I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

This claims to have some GUI functionality, but very slow! http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaguid/

Answer (score 0):

There was a VM for DOS called JavaPC.  It was discontinued a long time ago though and [this](http://www.realvnc.com/pipermail/vnc-list/1998-April/000884.html) is the only reference I can find.

Comment: That is not a JVM, it is a VNC client, to make a "network computer" out of a PC. Here is another: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/nino/dosvnc.html  Another slightly related fun link which turned up googling:  http://josh.com/tiny/