# How can Java Swing application auto start on DOS (Disk Operating System) startup?

Tags: java, swing, operating-system, jvm, dos

I want to create an application (Java Swing / Console), which will have some basic features of file management but, I want to run this Java application on pure DOS system. Is it possible? will the JVM be able to handle resources available on hardware?

NOTE: the java application should run automatically the moment DOS operating system is started. (I personally believe, this can be done if we install JVM on DOS and run configure console application on DOS startup. but have no idea about swing application)

Purpose:
I want to do this because this is an application which will be like customized operating system for my client. Dedicated for specific task.

Please, let me know is this the right direction to go on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. It will never work. When your OS don't support graphics, you cannot run any graphic application on it. In this case Java cannot access graphics features, which are defined by the OS and therefore cannot open any window (neither AWT/Swing nor JavaFX).

Comment: Thanks @SergiyMedvynskyy ! Do you know any other method to achieve this requirement? What about Java console application?

Comment: You can use `GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()` to determine whether your application runs in console environment. So when this method returns true, you can start your program as a console application. If false - your GUI may be shown.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151623/is-it-possible-to-run-java-gui-programs-under-dos-systems

Comment: Good luck finding a Java VM that you can install under MS-DOS.  There might have been one or two of them in the past but they'll be old and very much unsupported. You'd be better of just using something like Linux or FreeBSD and having it launch your application at start up.

Comment: Actually you are right! I am googling and gathering information. And i found Debian to be more comfortable for this particular requirement. Please let know more if anyone knows it more. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy DOS supports graphics, and has done so for more than 30 years.

Comment: @BernhardEriksson please read my comment completely. OS must not only support graphics, but also support Window manipulation mechanism (create it, bring it to front etc.).

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy you wrote that DOS can not run any graphic application. That is incorrect. Besides there are DOS-programs that have windows that can be manipulated. The problem here is that there is no current VM for DOS, and going for a lightweight Linux distribution is probably a much better sollution to the problem.